# How Mongo balancer work in regards to the hashed shard key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

It is well-know concept of balancing the data among nodes and it is clearly described in [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/). How does the balancer work in regards to the hashed shard key chunks? Can you migrate a chunk if according to the shard key the documents from this chunk belong to this shard? If it is not true, why then the documents are in the shard they do not belong to? Or the balancer is irrelevant for hashed shard key as long as the number of shards is not changing?

Answer (score 1):

Hashed shard key still performs like a normal range-based shard key. They also can be migrated, split, etc. just like a normal shard key.

The difference being: hashed shard key have some additional process when initially sharding a collection. To paraphrase from the docs page at [Hashed sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/):

When sharding a populated collection:

> The sharding operation creates the initial chunk(s) to cover the entire range of the shard key values. The number of chunks created depends on the configured chunk size.

When sharding an empty collection:

> The sharding operation creates empty chunks to cover the entire range of the shard key values and performs an initial chunk distribution. By default, the operation creates 2 chunks per shard and migrates across the cluster.

In short, hashed sharding presplit the whole hashed keyspace, then the balancer moves the chunks across the cluster like usual.

Other than the initial chunk splits, they function just like a normal shard key.

Note that hashed shard key can help if your shard key is very much monotonically increasing to prevent a "hot shard" and help to spread your writes across the whole cluster. Using a hashed shard key is not a guarantee that you cannot have jumbo chunks, since the cardinality of the hashed key will reflect the cardinality of the actual key.

For example: assuming that the hash algorithm is MD5 (128 bit in size). Potentially, the MD5 space is very large. However, if the underlying key (unhashed) value can only be either `A` or `B`, those two hashed with MD5 will always result in `A -> bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef` and `B -> 30cf3d7d133b08543cb6c8933c29dfd7`, making the cardinality extremely small.